# Prevent GNU Emacs Exiting While Composing Log Entry

Tags: git, svn, emacs, mercurial

Whenever I accidentally fat-finger `C-x C-c` (or `Cmd-Q` on a Mac), GNU Emacs exits right away unless shells are open or buffers, backed by files, are modified -- in which case it prompts as to how to proceed.

Unfortunately, if I've got no shell sessions open and have saved my files, but am in the midst of composing a brilliant, yet perhaps not entirely pithy, git log message (in the `*vc-log*` buffer), that won't prevent me exiting in one fell, promptless, swoop -- thus losing that draft, which apparently doesn't get autosaved anywhere that I've been able to find.

What's the best way to address this issue? I would think it's best for `*vc-log*`, and any other such buffer that provides for "on-the-fly" composition not backed by a traditional file (such as a commit/checkin message or email), to nevertheless be backed by a "pending draft" file. That would not only help avoid accidentally exiting Emacs, but allow restoring of such a draft if Emacs (or the computer itself) crashed.

If that's a reasonable approach, how should it be implemented?

Other approaches I've considered (which seem less than ideal):

- Somehow convince the pertinent Emacs exit hook to always prompt before exiting, even if there are no shell sessions nor modified, file-backed, buffers
- Use a fresh Emacs session, auto-invoked by (e.g.) `git commit` (with no `-m` option and assuming `GIT_EDITOR=emacs` in the environment), so the file-backed `COMMIT_EDITMSG` buffer is used to compose the commit message -- which prevents that new Emacs session from quitting without prompting **and** avoids accidentally quitting the original Emacs session (typically "fatter" with many buffers and other context)
- Use `git commit -m ...` for single-line commit messages
- Always keep a shell session open (within Emacs), so quitting always prompts first

Any recommendations?

Comment: For your first bullet: `(add-hook 'kill-emacs-query-functions
          (lambda () (y-or-n-p "Do you really want to exit Emacs? "))
          'append)`

Comment: I'm not sure if tagging all of git svn and mercurial is really necessary here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `confirm-kill-emacs` <kbd>RET</kbd>

allows you to set a confirmation prompt.